# Changing the output DXF version when exporting with ogr2ogr

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, dxf, osgeo4w

I am exporting a DXF file from a PostgreSQL database. If I use the OSGeo4W installed with the 3.8 vesrion of QGIS, the dxf version will be a newer one than what I would get if I would use the OSGeo4W installed with the QGIS 2.18. This means that my collague who has only an old AutoCAD 2007 cannot open it..
Is it possible to create an older version of DXF, like when I use 'Save As' in AutoCAD?
(I know I could save it in my AutoCAD for my collague, but I would like to create this directly)

The command I use:

```
ogr2ogr -f "DXF" d:\dir\mydxf.dxf "PG:host=myhost user=myuser dbname=mydb" -sql "select * from myschema.mytable"
```

I can not seem to find any option in the GDAL documentation regarding this problem.

Comment: Driver https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/dxf.html is documented to write "DXF files that are compatible with AutoCAD 2004 and later" so that problem should not exist. I suggest to make a test with newest GDAL version. It AutoCAD 2007 still can't open those files I would write mail to gdal-dev mailing list and make a bug report if the issue gets confirmed.

Comment: Thank you! I will do that!

Comment: @588chm have you found any workaround? Have you sent a message to the gdal-dev mailing list about this issue?

Comment: @AndreaGiudiceandrea I have not found a workaround other than opening in AutoCAD and saving it in an other version. 
I have not sent a message to them.